Google Sheets Macro Script to expand column group based on cell value
I have a sheet with a column group for each week of the year. i have a formula in cell A1 that has the current week numeric value. I want to use that in a macro to determine which cell grouping should be expanded. there are 10 columns for each grouping, so the first was at cellgroup 6, 1 and the next was at 16, 11
here is what i have, but it isnt working. i would appreciate any guidance. i code in VBA but this needs to exist in Google Sheets
    function test2() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();     
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
      var cellValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue();
      var cellGroup = cellValue + 5
      if (cellvalue = "1") {
        spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getColumnGroup((cellGroup), 1).expand();
      }
      else {
        spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getColumnGroup((cellGroup+10), 1).expand();
      }
    };

here is a test sheet with the groups
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-XwuSrn0NG8LdQV5uB3L3T0BvJ1kQufodCXq58ygO90

Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help us better understand your issue, please provide a sample sheet by editing the information above.

Script to expand column group based on cell value
I modified your script and you should be able to achieve what you like using this code.

You may try this:
function expand() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cellValue = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var getRowValue = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 2, 1, spreadsheet.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat()
  spreadsheet.getColumnGroup(getRowValue.indexOf(cellValue) + 2, 1).expand()
}
function collapse(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cellValue = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var getRowValue = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 2, 1, spreadsheet.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat()
  spreadsheet.getColumnGroup(getRowValue.indexOf(cellValue) + 2, 1).collapse()
}


To use and apply this code, setup your button and assign script.



Sample Output:


Reference:

indexOf
flat
range


you are amazing <3 thank you!

If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer
